# Como passar o index do ngFor no ngClass

Tags: angular

Estou tentando passar o `index` do `ngFor` dentro do `ngClass` para ativar a classe correta. Já tentei diversas formas, mas não consegui.

Segue o código:

```
<td *ngFor="let cell of row; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'col-tb-1-active' : classFocus.col1 , 'col-tb-1' : !classFocus.col1}">{{ cell.value }}</td>
```

Neste caso, onde tem "1" eu quero trocar pelo `index`. seria algo do tipo:

```
<td *ngFor="let cell of row; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'col-tb-i-active' : classFocus.coli , 'col-tb-i' : !classFocus.coli}">{{ cell.value }}</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você só precisa concatenar usando o `+`:

```
<td *ngFor="let cell of row; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'col-tb-' + i + '-active' : 'classFocus.col' + i , 'col-tb-' + i : !'classFocus.col'+ i}">{{ cell.value }}</td>
```

Fiz um exemplo no ***[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/zl5o4171q3)***

Comment: Tentei dessa forma, mas não funcionou.

Comment: @Bruno veja me exemplo adicionado a resposta!

Comment: Lá no exemplo funcionou. Porém, lá não tem uma condição no ngClass igual a que eu postei. Acredito que o problema esteja aí. Eu não estou no trabalho mais, qualquer coisa posso mandar um print dos erros amanhã. Obrigado pelo retorno e pela disposição!

Comment: @Bruno por nada, minha ideia é mostrar você como fazer, se tem algum erro no código é difícil de identificar porque completamente como está o seu sistema, compreende?

Comment: Entendo perfeitamente. Pelo exemplo que você postou, tentei alterar para [ngClass]="{'col-tb-' + i + '-active' : i > 0 , 'col-tb-' + i : i < 0}" Dessa forma seria mais ou menos o jeito que eu precisava, mas lá também não funcionou. Talvez esteja fazendo besteira, não sei.